# Denormalizing chat messages in Azure Tables

Tags: azure, chat, message, azure-table-storage, denormalization

I am building a server back-end for a mobile social network using Windows Azure.

I have these 3 entities:

1. Users - Stored in SQL Azure
2. Threads (sort of relations between **2 users** which are then able to send messages to each other) - Stored in SQL Azure
3. Messages - Stored in Azure Tables

As I store Messages in Azure Tables partitioned by Thread ID I expect good performance when chatting (sending/reading Messages to/from Threads).

But I also need to be able to provide users with a list of the most recent Threads (recent = contains the most recent message). In other words I need to order Threads by the last message date when displaying.

Scanning many different table partitions and looking for the messages will obviously be performance killer, so I need to somehow denormalize data to other table partitions to be able to fetch the most recent threads efficiently.

What based on your experience is the best strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: after further thinking, here is a better suggestion (I think):

Have one Message ATS table. This table will house two types of messages: messsage sent and message received.
Each time a user sends a message, store it in the table as "Sent" and then as "Received" (or whatever you want to call those types).

Partition all of the messages in the Message table by the following:

(UserId) - PartitionKey, (long.Max - Timestamp.Ticks) - RowKey

As extra properties you can store ThreadId, Sent/Received differentiation, etc.

If you want to guarantee that your message is inserted twice w/o problems, use Queue's and a Worker role.

This scheme partitions everything by the user.  You would be able to display all of the messages to/from that user within a time range and always descending.

Comment: Hi, Igorek and thanks for the answer! The problem I see in solution that you purpose is that each time user posts a message into thread I will have to query the SQL Azure for updating the conversation timestamp in the Thread table. Which kinda offsets the advantage of using Azure Tables - the scalability...

Comment: Igorek, thanks for updating the answer. Based on it I implemented something very similar, which works well, so I marked you answer accepted. However I found the discussion you had with FlorinDumitrescu (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/6a745a22-540a-44d5-b426-d42dd8510da5) and got confused about my previous "tables-are-more-scalable" worldview. So I am going to google it and eventually start a new discussion about it...

Comment: Hi.  Your original thinking is correct: ATS is more scaleable.  That's what I was highlighing in my responses on the MSDN forums as well.  5000 transactions/second/per account is decent!

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a batch process solution is always a workaround and reminds me of old computing like mainframe. There is nothing that can substitute online/real-time system.

If you choose a batch solution, it will make your system obsolete upon launch and will prevent any technological innovation in the future.

When your Azure databases begin to become too large to query, Microsoft recommends to use Federations. Basically it means to split your data across multiple databases and utilize compatible access logic in the code.

Start by looking at this demo app: [SQL Azure Federations Tutorial -- Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/SQL-Azure-Federation-a2d0eccf)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! If I understand your answer correctly you basically consider Azure Tables obsolete and recommend using Federations instead?

Comment: @Martin Šťáva, Azure Tables are not obsolete, but they are not very scalable from a throughput point of view. Their scalability limit is [5000 operations / second](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx) while Sql Azure Federations can go [a lot higher](http://www.ducons.com/blog/benchmarking-throughput-and-scalability-on-sql-azure-federations). Choose Federations if you need the flexibility of Azure Sql and high scalability. Choose Table Storage if you need low price on high volumes of data.

Comment: @FlorinDumitrescu, thanks for your answer, which I find very important. I found a discussion that you started here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/6a745a22-540a-44d5-b426-d42dd8510da5. I have to admin that the fact that azure table storage seems to be less scalable suprises me as well as the scalability is supposed to be it's major advantage over the sql azure. This is why it seemed natural to me to base the messaging on Azure Tables. Could you possibly elaborate more on this topic, did you get any answer from Microsoft on this one? Thanks!

Comment: @Martin Šťáva, the MSDN forum discussion you mention was carried before the launch of the SQL Azure Federations. In the mean time I have benchmarked Federations first hand and written an article [here](http://www.ducons.com/blog/benchmarking-throughput-and-scalability-on-sql-azure-federations). From a throughput point of view Federations are much more scalable then ATS, but that comes at a price which in this case is the price :). I stand by previous comment. Go for ATS if you want to store high volumes of data at low prices. Go for Federations if you need high scalability and SQL flexibility.